# Android activity is not created properly with Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I created a activity layout xml file with `ConstraintLayout`.  It had a nice look and feel when it was designing. But when I run that on a device it missed its structure as like as in design phase.

This is my xml layout file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
tools:context=".ui.AdMenuActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/bg_gradient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_225sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_gradient_next"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/image_ssb_main"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_55sdp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login to your account"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_90sdp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_280sdp"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_120sdp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:hint="Your Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/editText"
            android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:hint="Your Password"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/editText"
            android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="#009688"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/white_greyish"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this are images of its designing phase and running phase,

**Designing phase**

[image]

**Running Phase**
[image]

Is there any way to design this layout as like as in design phase ?

Comment: Issue is "340dp". It is device independent.

Comment: And also remove all `tools:..absolute..` field. Bacuse it is only showing in design phase.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya : When removing this 'tools:..absolute..", I couldn't get expected layout

Comment: For this simple layout don't use constraintlayout.

Comment: I think you need to learn [ConstaintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not used constraints properly in your layout.

1. The closing tag is missing add

```xml
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

at the end of your layout

2. What Wesely has said is absolutely correct avoid using

```xml
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY
```

```xml
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent
```

it is good to use constraints like this will place the view in the center of the screen

3. You need to constraint
   i) View   
   ii)ImageView  
   iii)TextView where you have written Login and Login to your account
    
   iv) Linear Layout

Hope this will help you 
Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Although below answer is not the solution for your problem but you can try it without `constraintlayout` because `constraintlayout` is used for making complex layouts and the design you want to achieve can be achieved using `linearlayout` easily.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_gradient_next"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/image_ssb_main" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login to your account"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                android:hint="Your Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/editText"
                android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                android:hint="Your Password"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/editText"
                android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#009688"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@color/white_greyish"
                android:text="Sign up"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AndroidStudio to help you to set those constraint.

And you must avoid use absolute margin like `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX`

Use these kinds of constraint instead.

```xml
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/someView"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

for example, if you want to set a View in the horizontal center, and align top of parent:

```xml
android:layout_margin="16dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

The tip is to set a `View` constraint to another views. Not all views are constraint with their parent.

Answer (score 1):

As I noticed, your top layout is Constraint layout and you are closing it with `</LinearLayout>` tag(Last line in xml)

And in constraint layout, each child must have at least one horizontal constraint and one vertical constraint. Otherwise children will not place properly in the parent.

Your layout can be replaced with the following. Give proper id to each child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
tools:context=".ui.AdMenuActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/bg_gradient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_225sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_gradient_next"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:src="@mipmap/image_ssb_main"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_15sdp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bg_gradient"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgView"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_55sdp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login to your account"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_90sdp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_280sdp"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_23sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_120sdp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:hint="Your Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/editText"
            android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLt1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:hint="Your Password"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/editText"
            android:textColor="#2C2C2C"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLt2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="#009688"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/white_greyish"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ConstraintLayout>
```